# How do you get the "Got Flair?" trophy/achievement?

Tags: achievements, fifa-17

So I am having some trouble with this trophy:

> **Got Flair?**
>
> Score a goal with a Flair Shot in a women's football match

When I look at the control instructions, it says flair shots can be done using <kbd>L2</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> which is the same as last year and I was fine with that.

Also, I am playing "Kick Off" mode with Women's Team. I am using Brazil and both my 2 forwards have the "Flair" trait (although I am not sure if that is a requirement?).

So, what am I doing wrong? Does it have to be done in a certain area? Or from a certain type of pass? (flair pass, cross, ground, etc.) No matter how much a play they just don't do anything other than a basic shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have finally worked out how to do it...

You don't need the player to have the "Flair" attribute but it does seem that you need somebody with a decent "skill moves" rating. I this case I did it with 4 stars skills rating.

The team I used was USA, and I played a 4-4-2 formation with Rapinoe and Heath up front. Who have 4-star skill and 5-star skill respectively.

I achieved the trophy with Rapinoe (4-star skills, no flair trait). However, the button combination I used was in fact <kbd>L2</kbd> + <kbd>R1</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>. I don't know if this is required, perhaps it just a variation modifier for flair moves... but it does do the job.

Took a few attempts but basically you don't need to receive from a pass, you can just run at the goal and press the button combo, and some times it will just do a flair shot instead of a normal shot. Net it and the trophy will pop.